# Losing colors after rotating an RGBA image using PIL

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to rotate an RGBA image using PIL, this is what the image looks like:

[image: An RGBA image]

But after rotating, it lost all RGB values at alpha = 0.

[image: Rotations]

I've tried all other resampling types for the rotate() function, but they even make things worse.

This is the original image: http://djosix.com/cell.png

Comment: Please provide the image!

Comment: When resampling, PIL is probably taking the average of the pixels weighted by the opacity. When the opacity is 0, that weighted average is degenerate.

Comment: Such chained functions are executed left to right. Apparently `rotate` cannot handle the original, so put `convert` in front.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I really need to preserve the alpha channel too. Is this a bug of PIL?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? You have not provided your actual image. You have shown you can go to greyscale, ok, good. You have shown you can remove the alpha channel, ok, good. You have shown you can rotate it and remove the alpha channel, ok, good. But what is your actual image and actual question? You also say you have tried all other sampling methods - in addition to what? And why? And how?

Comment: I found the problem here(https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/master/src/PIL/Image.py#L2324). PIL is trying to convert RGBA image into RGBa mode before calling transform(), which loses RGB values at alpha=0 after converting back to RGBA mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer:

```py
alpha = image.split()[-1]
image = image.convert('RGB').rotate(angle)
image.putalpha(alpha.rotate(angle))
```

---

Refer to the source code:

https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/master/src/PIL/Image.py#L2324

In `transform()`, called by `rotate()`:

```py
if self.mode == "RGBA":
    return (
        self.convert("RGBa")
        .transform(size, method, data, resample, fill, fillcolor)
        .convert("RGBA")
    )
```

Converting to RGBa will multiply RGB with Alpha according to this part:

https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/master/src/libImaging/Convert.c#L489

```c
static void
rgbA2rgba(UINT8* out, const UINT8* in, int xsize)
{
    int x;
    unsigned int alpha, tmp;
    for (x = 0; x < xsize; x++) {
        alpha = in[3];
        *out++ = MULDIV255(*in++, alpha, tmp);
        *out++ = MULDIV255(*in++, alpha, tmp);
        *out++ = MULDIV255(*in++, alpha, tmp);
        *out++ = *in++;
    }
}
```